# C# - MyClass.MyProperty[something]

Tags: c#

I want to do something but not sure how to describe it. I have this class

```
public class Company {
  private List<Person> _persons;
  private Person GetPersonByName(string name) {
    // My code to select Person is here, which is fine
  }
}
```

But I want to be able to do this

```
Company c;
Person p = c.Persons["John"];
```

which should implicitly call GetPersonByName("John").

Is that possible? What do I need to add to the Company class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to create an accessor class, like the following:

```
public class Company
{
    private List<Person> _persons;
    public class PersonsIndexer
    {
        Company _owner;
        public PersonsIndexer(Company owner)
        {
            _owner = owner;
        }
        public Person this[string name]
        { 
            get
            {
                 return _owner._persons.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == name); // or whatever code you have there
            }
        }
    }

    public PersonsIndexer Persons{ get; private set; }

    public Company() 
    {
        Persons = new PersonsIndexer(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like what I need! I don't have time to test it so I'll just accept it now. Thank you Zruty and everyone for your quick responses!

Comment: Perfect! I'd give a +10 if I could, very clear answer that works on first try, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

That's called [indexed property in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
public class Company
{
    private List<Person> _persons;
    private Person GetPersonByName(string name)
    {
        // My code to select Person is here, which is fine
    }

    public Person this[string name]
    {
        get { return GetPersonByName(name); }
    }
}
```

then you can get a person by:

```
Company c;
Person p = c["John"];
```

However if you want `c.Persons["John"]`, then you have to define a property Persons, which is of some user defined type, which has the indexed property defined. You can have the Persons property be of type List, but then the List class has no indexed property that takes string.
Why don't you just use a method `GetPerson(string name)` ?

Comment: ah... thanks for that... So you're saying it's impossible to do c.Persons["John"]?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
Persons["John"];
```

you are using the indexer on the whatever type the Persons underlying object is, in this case the List. What you want is possible by two ways, and probably more, but these are my ideas at the moment:

First approach: you can create a special collection List (lets say PersonList : List) which would override the indexer, and in the constructor pass the Company instance, so that in the override implementation you can query the customer instance.

> ```
> public class PersonList: List<Person>
> {
>     public new Person this[string name]
>     {
>          get
>          {
>              return company.GetMyPerson(name);
>          }
>     }
> }
> ```

Second approach: you create an indexer on Company class directly, and have something like c["John"]

Now about these approaches -> First one looks better from my point of view, because it violates less design principles. Querying the company with indexer for persons in the second approach is not really nice ...